# Subset Data Based on Column Attributes

Tags: r, attributes

I want to subset `data` table based on specific value of column `attribute` value. In below example it will be `2200`.

Following code **won't** help for big data. I want to follow an optimized approach which applies to larger data set.

```
> identical(attr(data[,1], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] FALSE
> identical(attr(data[,1], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] FALSE
> identical(attr(data[,2], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] TRUE
> identical(attr(data[,3], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] TRUE
> identical(attr(data[,4], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] TRUE
> identical(attr(data[,5], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] FALSE
> identical(attr(data[,6], "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber, "2200")
[1] FALSE
```

Also, `attr()` doesn't accept all the columns at once. Any suggestions on how creating subset based on `attribute` values can be done recursively and efficiently?

---

**Reproducible Data**

```
column1 <- rep(-0.01, 8)
attr(column1, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "1200"
column2 <- rep(0.05, 8)
attr(column2, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "2200"
column3 <- rep(-0.01, 8)
attr(column3, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "2200"
column4 <- rep(0.05, 8)
attr(column4, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "2200"
column5 <- rep(-0.01, 8)
attr(column5, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "5200"
column6 <- rep(0.05, 8)
attr(column6, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber <- "6200"

data <- data.frame(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
```

**Output of Above Data**

```
> attr(data$column1, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "1200"
> attr(data$column2, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "2200"
> attr(data$column3, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "2200"
> attr(data$column4, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "2200"
> attr(data$column5, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "5200"
> attr(data$column6, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber
[1] "6200"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sapply` should do it. Based on your reproducible `dataframe`, the following code will yield your desired result:

```
data[, sapply(data, function(x) attr(x, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber == "2200")]
```

Comment: .@TroyVo - I was trying this, even had this in my question before I edited it. Didn't use `function()` as I thought `identical()` should do it when used with `sapply()`.

Comment: .@TroyVo - Do you think this code will be good to have two conditions at once: `data[, sapply(data, function(x) attr(x, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber == "2200") & sapply(data, is.double)]`?

Comment: You can incorporate that into your sapply.

Comment: data[, sapply(data, function(x) attr(x, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber == "2200" & is.double(x))]